# xmlXPathEval: 2 object left on the stack What does this error mean?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm writing a script using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). Scrapy makes heavy usage of `HtmlXPathSelector`. When I scrap my pages I get the following error:

```
Invalid type
xmlXPathEval: 2 object left on the stack
```

I really don't get what that error means and how to get rid of it, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should post the xpath query

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of the Python script (including the XPath) and the source markup.